# as adjective as

Tags: grammar

Given sentence:

> It is colder today than it was yesterday.

Possible answers:

> 1.It was not as cold yesterday as **it is** today.
>   2.It was not as cold yesterday as today.

Which is better? Do we need to add *subject verb* after "as"?

Comment: They're both fine. Obviously *neither* is particularly likely, given the speaker is much more likely to be interested in talking about what it's like ***now** = today*, rather than what it *wasn't* like yesterday. And note that any natural spoken context would almost certainly contract ***wasn't***, but because ***is*** is "stressed", that one couldn't be contracted. This makes the "stress" stand out even more, but that's probably not specifically "wanted", so mostly native speakers wouldn't include it at all.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but I think it's a more natural way to say it: _It was warmer yesterday than it is today_.

Comment: @J.R.: That depends on the climate. OP seems to be in the northern latitudes. ^_^